# Install solution automatically after adding solution using powershell

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell

I am using powershell to update and deploy solutions

UpdateSolution.ps1

```
Add-SPSolution -Identity SomeWP.wsp -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot\SomeWP.wsp -GACDeployment
Add-SPSolution -Identity SomeWP.wsp -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot\SomeWP.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Deploy Solution.ps1

```
param([string]$workspaceUrl)
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
Install-SPSolution –Identity SomeWP.wsp –WebApplication $workspaceUrl –GACDeployment -Force
Install-SPSolution –Identity SomeWP.wsp –WebApplication $workspaceUrl –GACDeployment -Force
}
)
```

Now if I run Update.ps1 and wait for sometime and then run Deploy.ps1, it works fine, but if I run them one after the other it says

> Install-SPSolution : A deployment or retraction is already under way
>   for the solution "someWP.wsp", and only one deployment or retraction
>   at a time is supported.

Now how can I automate this? like once the update is complete, I want to run deploy automatically

Comment: Is there some reason you need to run `Install-SPSolution` on the same WSP you just updated?  To my understanding, that is redundant.  `Update-SPSolution` will update a WSP "live", so to speak, and it will remain deployed (but now updated).  You would only need to run `Install-SPSolution` if you had retracted and removed the WSP, which you bypassed by running `Update-SPSolution` in the first place.

Comment: oh okay. I was not aware of it, thought it should be deployed after updating 
So I need to perform install only if I add solution?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If you add a new solution with `Add-SPSolution` then you need to run `Install-SPSolution` to deploy it.  But once it's deployed, `Update-SPSolution` is all you need.

Comment: Addressing your edit: have you actually tried it this way?  Previously, you were running `Install` after `Update`, but `Update` causes a re-deployment of the solution, which is why you would get the error "A deployment...is already underway".  `Add` does not trigger a deployment (which is why you have to run `Install` after it), so you may not get the same error....

Answer (score 0):

I have good success using powershell DSC to install and update solutions. For example this block install and deploys the solution.

```
SPFarmSolution appointment.workflow.v.1.0.0.wsp
        {
            Name                  = "appointment.workflow.v.1.0.0.wsp"
            LiteralPath           = "path to solution"
            Ensure                = "Present"
            Version               = "1.0.0"
            WebApplications       = @("https.dev.com")
            Deployed              = $true
            PsDscRunAsCredential  = $Script:FarmAdmin
        }
```

To remove, change "deployed" to false and Ensure  "Absent". I have used this method to update custom solutions across several dozen farms.

The workflow:
The solution is updated and the version number is changed. 
Solution is uploaded to DSC Pull server
DSC Script is run to uninstall old solution
Script is updated to install new solution
New script is then run

It has worked pretty well for me